# Logstash S3 input plugin - filter based on time modified

Tags: date, amazon-s3, filter, logstash

I have a Logstash container that is configured to read objects from S3.
The requirement is to filter old objects, let's say objects before 3 months should be dropped.

I noticed that I can expose the s3 metadata, so I have the following metadata in each event:

```
"@metadata" => {
    "s3" => {
                          "etag" => "\"xxx"",
                "content_length" => 33,
                      "metadata" => {},
                    "version_id" => "null",
                 "accept_ranges" => "bytes",
                 "last_modified" => 2021-12-21T13:30:28.000Z,
```

Maybe there is a filter/ruby code that I can use in order to filter "old" objects and drop them?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is [drop filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) in logstash and you can use it in combination with `if` to drop events that match the condition like this example from documentation:

```
filter {
  if [loglevel] == "debug" {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

Besides this you will also need a way to check how old is event. For that you can use [age filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-age.html). Quoting documentation:

> This filter calculates the age of an event by subtracting the event
> timestamp from the current timestamp. You can use this plugin with the
> drop filter plugin to drop Logstash events that are older than some
> threshold.

This plugin seem to work directly with `@timestamp` field, so you'll have to do a little bit of shuffling around your fields.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Filip, I posted the answer and didn't notice that you write.
Your approach is correct, to use the age filter based on the timestamp.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So, I after investigations and help from the Logsatsh community, I managed to handle this requirement as follows

1. Use the mutate plugin in order to copy the last modified time to the timestamp

   mutate {
   copy => { "[@metadata][s3][last_modified]" => "@timestamp"}
   }
2. Use the age plugin in order to filter based on the changed timestamp

   age{}
   if [@metadata][age] > ${number in seconds} {
   drop {}
   }